# How to use theme() for plugin.withOptions in tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

So I want to use this tailwindcss plugin, and I need to have custom color.
This is based on [tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#exposing-advanced-configuration-options).

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    require('@gradin/tailwindcss-scrollbar')({
      colors: {
        track: 'lightgray',
        thumb: 'gray',
        thumbHover: 'darkgray',
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

But I want to use colors from theme. Both of these don't work, I still get the plugin default config.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    require('@gradin/tailwindcss-scrollbar')({
      colors: theme => ({
        track: theme('colors.gray.200'),
        thumb: theme('colors.primary.200'),
        thumbHover: theme('colors.primary.500'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    require('@gradin/tailwindcss-scrollbar')(theme => ({
      colors: {
        track: theme('colors.gray.200'),
        thumb: theme('colors.primary.200'),
        thumbHover: theme('colors.primary.500'),
      },
    })),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that You are actually author of this plugin, and plugin is problem, not tailwind config.

In plugin source You used `plugin.withOptions` for theming, and this is wrong. In tailwind config there is already "theme" section, and this is the place where all theme options should go, also for plugins.

Plugin "options" are used only for very specific options, like prefix class etc, NOT for styling.

From [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#exposing-advanced-configuration-options):

> Sometimes it makes sense for a plugin to be configurable in a way that
> doesn't really belong under theme or variants, like perhaps you want
> users to be able to customize the class name your plugin uses.
>
> For cases like this, you can use plugin.withOptions to define a plugin
> that can be invoked with a configuration object.

Take a look at other plugins, for ex. [tailwindcss-typography](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography)

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      typography: {
        DEFAULT: {
          css: {
            color: '#333',
            a: {
              color: '#3182ce',
              '&:hover': {
                color: '#2c5282',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Comment: I use withOptions because I thought that theme is just for when you need to add more styles in addition to DEFAULT. Thanks for the explanation